# Assign sequential numbers to rows with repeating values

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, window-functions

I have the following table:

```
ITEM    DATE        VALUE
----------------------
ITEM1   2016-05-04  1
ITEM1   2016-05-05  3
ITEM1   2016-05-06  3
ITEM1   2016-05-09  3
ITEM1   2016-05-04  4
ITEM2   2016-05-10  1
ITEM2   2016-05-05  2
ITEM2   2016-05-06  3
ITEM2   2016-05-09  1
ITEM2   2016-05-10  1
```

And I want to get out, per item, how many entries back in time the value column has been the same (flat):

```
ITEM    DATE    VALUE   NUM_FLAT_ENTRYPOINTS
------------------------------
ITEM1   2016-05-04  1   0
ITEM1   2016-05-05  3   0 
ITEM1   2016-05-06  3   1
ITEM1   2016-05-09  3   2
ITEM1   2016-05-10  4   0
ITEM2   2016-05-04  1   0
ITEM2   2016-05-05  2   0
ITEM2   2016-05-06  3   0
ITEM2   2016-05-09  1   0
ITEM2   2016-05-10  1   1
```

My initial though would be:

```
select 
    *,
    rank()-1 over (partition by ITEM,VALUE order by DATE) as NUM_FLAT_ENTRYPOINTS 
from my_table
```

This, however, does not work as ITEM2 would partition 2016-05-04, 2016-05-09 and 2016-05-10 together and show 2 instead of 1 for NUM_FLAT_ENTRYPOINTS for the last line.

I am using Microsoft SQL Server 2008.

Any ideas?

Edit:

In Oracle (and possible other SQL Servers) it seems I can just do

```
select
    count(VALUE)-1 over (partition by ITEM,VALUE order by DATE) as NUM_FLAT_ENTRYPOINTS 
from my_table
```

but as far as I can tell this syntax does not work in SQL Server 2008. Any way to work around it?

Comment: I assume in your sample data the last lines for each item should be `2016-05-10`, not `2016-05-04`, and that `DATE` defines the order in which rows should be evaluated? Otherwise, please elaborate on what the rules are here...

Comment: You are correct sir, fixed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like a variation of gaps-and-islands.

**Sample data**

```
DECLARE @T TABLE (ITEM varchar(50), dt date, VALUE int);
INSERT INTO @T(ITEM, dt, VALUE) VALUES
('ITEM1', '2016-05-04', 1),
('ITEM1', '2016-05-05', 3),
('ITEM1', '2016-05-06', 3),
('ITEM1', '2016-05-09', 3),
('ITEM1', '2016-05-10', 4),
('ITEM2', '2016-05-04', 1),
('ITEM2', '2016-05-05', 2),
('ITEM2', '2016-05-06', 3),
('ITEM2', '2016-05-09', 1),
('ITEM2', '2016-05-10', 1);
```

**Query**

```
WITH
CTE
AS
(
    SELECT
        ITEM
        ,dt
        ,VALUE
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ITEM ORDER BY dt) AS rn1
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ITEM, VALUE ORDER BY dt) AS rn2
    FROM @T
)
SELECT
    ITEM
    ,dt
    ,VALUE
    ,rn1-rn2 AS rnDiff
    ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
        (PARTITION BY ITEM, VALUE, rn1-rn2 ORDER BY dt) - 1 AS NUM_FLAT_ENTRYPOINTS
FROM CTE
ORDER BY ITEM, dt;
```

**Result**

```
+-------+------------+-------+--------+----------------------+
| ITEM  |     dt     | VALUE | rnDiff | NUM_FLAT_ENTRYPOINTS |
+-------+------------+-------+--------+----------------------+
| ITEM1 | 2016-05-04 |     1 |      0 |                    0 |
| ITEM1 | 2016-05-05 |     3 |      1 |                    0 |
| ITEM1 | 2016-05-06 |     3 |      1 |                    1 |
| ITEM1 | 2016-05-09 |     3 |      1 |                    2 |
| ITEM1 | 2016-05-10 |     4 |      4 |                    0 |
| ITEM2 | 2016-05-04 |     1 |      0 |                    0 |
| ITEM2 | 2016-05-05 |     2 |      1 |                    0 |
| ITEM2 | 2016-05-06 |     3 |      2 |                    0 |
| ITEM2 | 2016-05-09 |     1 |      2 |                    0 |
| ITEM2 | 2016-05-10 |     1 |      2 |                    1 |
+-------+------------+-------+--------+----------------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the correction to the sample data I suggested in the comments, this seems to fit the bill:

```
declare @t table (ITEM char(5), Date date, Value tinyint)
insert into @t(ITEM,DATE,VALUE) values
('ITEM1','20160504',1),
('ITEM1','20160505',3),
('ITEM1','20160506',3),
('ITEM1','20160509',3),
('ITEM1','20160510',4),
('ITEM2','20160504',1),
('ITEM2','20160505',2),
('ITEM2','20160506',3),
('ITEM2','20160509',1),
('ITEM2','20160510',1)

;With Ordered as (
    select
        Item,
        Date,
        Value,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Item ORDER BY Date) as rn
    from @t
)
select
    *,
    COALESCE(rn -
        (select MAX(o2.rn) from Ordered o2
        where o2.ITEM = o.ITEM and
            o2.rn < o.rn and
            o2.Value != o.Value) - 1
    , o.rn - 1) as NUM_FLAT_ENTRYPOINTS
from
    Ordered o
```

That is, we assign row numbers (separately for each item), and then we simply find the latest row number earlier than the current one where `Value` is different. Subtracting these row numbers (and a further 1) produces the answer we need - assuming such an earlier row can be found. If there's no such earlier row then we're obviously in a sequence that's at the start for a particular item - so we just subtract 1 from the row number.

I've gone for "obviously correct" here - it's possible that there's a way to produce the result that may perform better but I'm not aiming for that right now.

Results:

```
Item  Date       Value rn                   NUM_FLAT_ENTRYPOINTS
----- ---------- ----- -------------------- --------------------
ITEM1 2016-05-04 1     1                    0
ITEM1 2016-05-05 3     2                    0
ITEM1 2016-05-06 3     3                    1
ITEM1 2016-05-09 3     4                    2
ITEM1 2016-05-10 4     5                    0
ITEM2 2016-05-04 1     1                    0
ITEM2 2016-05-05 2     2                    0
ITEM2 2016-05-06 3     3                    0
ITEM2 2016-05-09 1     4                    0
ITEM2 2016-05-10 1     5                    1
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT ITEM, [DATE], VALUE,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ITEM, VALUE, grp 
                          ORDER BY [DATE]) - 1 AS NUM_FLAT_ENTRYPOINTS 
FROM (
SELECT ITEM, [DATE], VALUE,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ITEM ORDER BY [DATE]) - 
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ITEM, VALUE ORDER BY [DATE]) AS grp
FROM mytable) AS t
```